# The file stderr.log of SSO Tomcat not showing credentials obtained

Tags: java, tomcat, logging, single-sign-on, business-objects

Trying to set up SSO on SAP  BI 4.3 SP3 environment.

Then get to the part where we have set up global.properties and entered the following lines in Tomcat settings:(java options)

-`Djava.security.auth.login.config=c:\windows\bscLogin.conf`
-`Djava.security.krb5.conf=c:\windows\krb5.ini`
-`Djcsi.kerberos.debug=true`
-`Dsun.security.krb5.debug=true`
-`Djcsi.kerberos.maxpacketsize=0`

When we restart tomcat, stderr.log does not contain the message ‘Credentials Obtained’.

Any idea what we could be doing wrong?

Thanks

I checked all the files of configuration and they seem right

Comment: You are going to get more engagement on this question [here](https://answers.sap.com/index.html) or [here](https://bobj-board.org/).